# How to do an action when flutter app lunch url close

Tags: flutter, payment-gateway

I am building a flutter app that integrates with payment gateway through API
when I do HTTP Post request to the API, the gateway reply with Iframe (URL), where the user should use to enter his credit card details and complete payment.

I am using Lunch_url to open the Iframe recevied like this.

```
 Future CompetePaymntProcess(
   String paymentid, Map<String, dynamic> transactionresult) async {
   String iframe = transactionresult["data"]["iframe_url"];
   await launchUrlString(iframe);
}
```

Now I would like to do some actions based on the result of the user payment when he closes the web browser opened by LaunchURLString.

These actions are to send one more request to the API to get te payment result and do update my records.

How can I trigger an action when this web Browser is closed?

I did some research and found on Flutter web there is the below code:

```
 html.window.onBeforeUnload.listen((event) async {}
```

Is there anything similar in flutter app? or what is the best practice in my case?

Edit - Adding my tried code for Webview_Flutter Widget

```
 class _WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WebView(
    initialUrl: paymentiframe,
    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
    navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
     print("Navigation is detected");
     if (request.url.startsWith('https://valleysys.net')) {
      print('blocking navigation to $request}');
    }
    return NavigationDecision.prevent;
    },
    onPageStarted: (String url) {
    print("Started $url");
   },
  );
 }
```

Problem: Navigation Delegate never gets called, OnPageStarted only get called once when the Iframe is opened, but doesn't sense any navigation happening.

Code for Flutter_webview_plugin

```
 @override
 void initState() {
 final flutterWebviewPlugin = new FlutterWebviewPlugin();
 flutterWebviewPlugin.launch(paymentiframe);

 flutterWebviewPlugin.onUrlChanged.listen((String url) {
  print("Url Change is Detected");
  print(url);
  if (url == "https://valleysys.net") {
    print("Navigation to return URL");
    Navigator.of(context).pop();
  }
});

super.initState();
```

}

same problem is here, it detects the url only once when the first Iframe is opened, but doesn't get called again when the url is changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use webview which has a navigation delegate. Once the user enters the details navigate the user to another page which webview can capture

```dart
WebView(
        initialUrl: 'https://flutter.dev',
        javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
        navigationDelegate: (NavigationRequest request) {
          if (request.url.startsWith('https://www.youtube.com/')) {
            print('blocking navigation to $request}');
//You can add your logic here
            return NavigationDecision.prevent;

          }
          
        },
      ),
```

https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter/example

Comment: Hello, thanks. Didn’t get the concept. Can u illustrate how will I perform my actions when the user close this webview widget?

Comment: You will have a URL to do the payment and you can also provide a redirect url for success and failure. So once the user finishes payment it will navigate to the redirect url, which can be listened by the navigation deligate

Comment: Thanks I got it, but I guess in this case the payment gateway itself should be rediercting the user to this redirect url. Not sure if the one I am using has this option. Will check. Thanks

Comment: It should definitely have a redirection url. 99% of gateways has this option..

Comment: This library has a bug, it doesn’t display Keyboard when a textfield is pressed.

Comment: No i can use keyboard when i use this package. Please check implementation again

Comment: Solved by upgrading to latest version. Thanks. working now.

Comment: hello again, navigation delegate has a common bug with andriod and not being called at all. is there anyway to match the return url rather than this method?

Comment: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin this is also a good plugin. You get a callback on url change

Comment: Still the same problem, the listner only detect the change in the first time when iframe is opened, then it doesn't detect any change after that. I also tried OnPageStarted and OnPageFinished in the first plugin, it only detect the change for the first iframe link, then any change after that is not detected (the redirection to the return url).

Comment: I can also see the below output "I/chromium( 4895): [INFO:CONSOLE(0)] "Error with Permissions-Policy header: Origin trial controlled feature not enabled: 'interest-cohort'.", source:  (0)" .. can't understand what is the issue.

Comment: There is definitely some issue in the implementation. I use these plugins on a regular basis and it works fine. Can you include your codes here please

Comment: I've edited the question with the two codes for both packages. I am wondering can it be something related to the gateway itself? the return url is opend normally after the transacion compete, but I am just checking.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/247492/discussion-between-kaushik-chandru-and-sherif-said-elahl).